# Perl: Error code returned to open3 after killed program

Tags: bash, shell, perl, exit-status

This program shows which error is returned to `open3` when running either `sleep 3` or `true;sleep 3` and `sleep` is killed:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                           
doit() {
  shell="$1"
  prg="$2"
  (sleep 2 && killall sleep) &
  perl -MIPC::Open3 -e 'open3($a,$b,$c,"'$shell'","-c","'"$prg"'"); wait; print $?>>8,"\n"'
}
export -f doit
parallel -j1 --tag doit \
  ::: ash bash csh dash fdsh fish fizsh ksh ksh93 mksh posh rc sash sh static-sh tcsh yash zsh \
  ::: '/bin/sleep 3' 'true;/bin/sleep 3'
```

On my system it gives:

```
ash /bin/sleep 3        143
ash true;/bin/sleep 3   143
bash /bin/sleep 3       0
bash true;/bin/sleep 3  143
csh /bin/sleep 3        143
csh true;/bin/sleep 3   143
dash /bin/sleep 3       143
dash true;/bin/sleep 3  143
fdsh /bin/sleep 3       143
fdsh true;/bin/sleep 3  143
fish /bin/sleep 3       143
fish true;/bin/sleep 3  143
fizsh /bin/sleep 3      143
fizsh true;/bin/sleep 3 143
ksh /bin/sleep 3        0
ksh true;/bin/sleep 3   0
ksh93 /bin/sleep 3      0
ksh93 true;/bin/sleep 3 0
mksh /bin/sleep 3       0
mksh true;/bin/sleep 3  143
posh /bin/sleep 3       143
posh true;/bin/sleep 3  143
rc /bin/sleep 3 1
rc true;/bin/sleep 3    1
sash /bin/sleep 3       255
sash true;/bin/sleep 3  0
sh /bin/sleep 3 143
sh true;/bin/sleep 3    143
static-sh /bin/sleep 3  143
static-sh true;/bin/sleep 3     143
tcsh /bin/sleep 3       143
tcsh true;/bin/sleep 3  143
yash /bin/sleep 3       0
yash true;/bin/sleep 3  0
zsh /bin/sleep 3        0
zsh true;/bin/sleep 3   0
```

All of the programs returning 143 I can explain. But what causes the other error values? I am especially puzzled by `bash` which gives 2 different values.

Answer (score 2):

For the

```
bash /bin/sleep 3       0
```

case we can observe this with `strace`

```
$ strace -f -e trace=process bash -c 'sleep 1'
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "sleep 1"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7fe3740) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "1"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7fe3740) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
$
```

which without any `TERM` signals happening shows that `bash` replaces itself with `sleep`; by contrast the compound `true;sleep 3` form will instead show a `clone` (if on Linux) as `bash` instead forks out the `sleep` and handles the exit code.

With a `SIGTERM` involved, we see:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=process bash -c 'sleep 999'
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "sleep 999"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7fe3740) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "999"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7fe3740) = 0
--- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3896, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGTERM +++
$ echo $?
143
$
```

This brings us to the Perl code, which is incorrect; [in Perl `$?` represents the 16-bit status word](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlvar.pod#$?) from `wait(2)`, and not whatever value a shell has mangled that 16-bit status word into. Your `print $?>>8` prints only the exit code information, which for a signal is indeed 0. If instead a correct inspection of the contents of `$?` is used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.14.0;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3 qw(open3);

my ( $input, $output, $err );
open3( $input, $output, $err, qw(bash -c), "sleep 999" );
wait;

if ( $? == -1 ) {
    say "noexec $!";
} elsif ( $? & 127 ) {
    printf "died signal=%d core=%s\n",
                 ( $? & 127 ), ( $? & 128 ) ? 'yea' : 'nay';
} else {
    say "exit ", $? >> 8;
}
```

Then Perl will report for the `bash -c 'sleep 3'` kill case properly:

```
$ perl ipcopenfoo
died signal=15 core=nay
$
```

Comment: How do I get Perl to give me the '143' that I get, if I replace your code with: `#!/bin/bash\n sleep 999;echo $?` ?

Comment: Copy how the shell mangles the value, probably 128 + ( $? & 127 ) and I don't know whether the shell does anything special when the there-was-a-coredump bit is set.